# Изменение роли без переавторизации

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-3

У пользователя А несколько ролей, одна из которых "viewer".
Удаляю роль:

```
await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>().AddUserToRolesAsync("A", new List<string>() { "viewer" });
```

После удаления в БД роль пропадает. Пользователь пытается получить доступ к:

```
 [Authorize]
 public class JournalController : Controller
 {
  [HttpGet]
  [Authorize(Roles = "viewer")]
  public ActionResult New()
  {   
   return View();
  }
}
```

И метод  New контроллера JournalController запускается. Если пользователь перезайдет все работает корректно. Метод New не работает.

Как как ограничить доступ сразу после удаления?

Comment: похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222127/microsoft-identity-removing-user-from-role-but-user-still-has-access-untill-l